# are there any cons to not using the table column length

Tags: mysql, pdo

I was fiddling around with a database and noticed i was able to add an integer with a length of 8 into a column (`int(4)`).

Are there any cons of exceeding the specified length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barmar is right on target. I am adding examples in this answer. There are no significant cons for exceeding the specified length. My preference is to use INT (without providing its length) for simplicity.

Int will allow storage of -2147483648 to 2147483647 for signed and 0 to 4294967295 for unsigned regardless of whether you use int(1), int(4), int or even int(45).

```
create table test (id int(45));

show create table test\G
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

insert into test values (2147483647);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

insert into test values (2147483648);
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1
```

This example just illustrates how length specified for int doesn't affect the storage of information in an int column. You can expect the same results if the table was int(1).

```
create table test(id int);

show create table test\G
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

If length is not included in INT's declaration, int(11) is assumed by MySQL (my version is 5.6.14 Community)

**Display length example**

```
create table test(id int(45) zerofill);
insert into test values (2147483647);
select * from test;
```

The result of this will be

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| id                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 000000000000000000000000000000000002147483647 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Another example

```
create table test(id int(2) zerofill);
insert into test values (2147483647);
select * from test;
```

The result of this will be

```
+------------+
| id         |
+------------+
| 2147483647 |
+------------+
```

Hope this information helps.

Comment: Thanks for all the examples and explanation

Answer (score 2):

For integer types, the width is just used for display purposes, it has no impact on the values that can be stored in the column. That's controlled by choosing between the types `tinyint`, `smallint`, `mediumint`, `int`, and `bigint`.

See [Numeric Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Comment: Thanks Barmar! I was expecting an error, but I now see what is going on. I just tested it out for varchar and that length does have effect, nice to see this difference, thanks!